# Oculus devices network without internet disconnects

Tags: android, adb, wifi, multiplayer, oculusquest

I have an issue with the Meta Quest 2 and the new Meta Quest Pro, where i have an app that needs to be connected to a local network to work (the same as the others headsets because it's multiplayer). This network does not have internet connection, which makes the headsets automatically disconnect from it. Is there a way to avoid this? We need the network to be always connected despite it having no internet.

A configuration or something that can be done to avoid this?

I try to use that adb command `settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0`, but doesn't work.
I was hoping this would avoid the headset from automatically disconnecting from networks without wifi. It doesn't :(